# Javascript Factorialize returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if anyone can tell me why this returns 100 and not 120? It should calculate the total number of the factor.

```
function factorialize(num) {

  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++ ) {
    var fact = i+i;    
    total = fact * fact;
  }
  return total;
}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: Take debugger and step through your code. That's what debugger is for.

Comment: Learn to rubberduck-debug your programs. Five lines of code are easy enough to debug yourself. Especially if it’s a factorial function that has billions of examples all over the internet.

Comment: Im using a web tool which doesn't seem to directly provide the code to be debugged.

Comment: @theHussle But you are using a web browser right now to ask this question, are you not? Every modern web browser has a console with debugging capabilities.

Comment: Hint: What does the second line inside the for loop do?

Comment: The console doesn't display anything, I've tried using console.log as mentioned in the question. Ok sorry didn't add that

Comment: Its being done in an online tool which DOES NOT allow access directly to the Javascript code.

Comment: @theHussle for what it's worth you could just copy/paste this code into your developer console (F12 or right click > inspect) and debug it there.

Comment: Thanks Paarth, I didn't know that. if you post as an answer I can upvote.

Comment: To calculate factorial in a loop, you need to multiply the previous total by the current number. You're just multiplying the current number by itself, replacing `total` each time. It's not building on the previous value at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate the factorial, use this code:

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var total = 1; // Initialize the total. 0! = 1.
  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++ ) {

    total = total * i; // Add the current index to the factors by multiplying it by the current total.
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: Could you quickly explain why I need to declare total outside the loop?

Comment: @theHussle because it is a running product. You initialize it as 1 because the default case, when num is zero and the loop doesn't run, the answer is 1, because math. You might want to [read up on factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Comment: That wasn't quite the question. @theHussle you don't necessarily need to declare the variable outside the loop (though it is a good idea). However, you do need to assign its initial value outside the loop because if you don't you'll just overwrite it with what you have this time, throwing away all the work you did in previous iterations of the loop

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct way to calculate the factorial. What is happening in your code is, the last time the line `total = fact * fact;` is run, `fact` has a value of 10 (because `i` is 5), so 10 * 10 becomes 100 and that is what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR is you're overwriting all the values of `fact`. `var` is scoped to a function in JS. Eventually you reach `i = 5`, which eventually sets fact to `(5+5) * (5+5)` which is 100.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense.